# Get private property of a private property using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

```
public class Foo
{
    private Bar FooBar {get;set;}

    private class Bar
    {
        private string Str {get;set;}
        public Bar() {Str = "some value";}
    }
 }
```

If I've got something like the above and I have a reference to Foo, how can I use reflection to get the value Str out Foo's FooBar?  I know there's no actual reason to ever do something like this (or very very few ways), but I figure there has to be a way to do it and I can't figure out how to accomplish it.

edited because I asked the wrong question in the body that differs from the correct question in the title

Comment: What have you tried?  A bit of google and some trial and error and you should have this done in no time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access private fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862747/access-private-fields)

Comment: This really isn't a difficult thing to do, its not all that dissimilar from public ones, you just need to specify different `BindingFlags`.

Comment: My question is different in that every example I've found here only goes one level deep.  I typed out the wrong question in the body of the question that differed from the question correctly asked in the title

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the [`GetProperty` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y4s51k3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) along with the `NonPublic` and `Instance` binding flags.

Assuming you have an instance of `Foo`, `f`:

```
PropertyInfo prop =
    typeof(Foo).GetProperty("FooBar", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

MethodInfo getter = prop.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);
object bar = getter.Invoke(f, null);
```

*Update*:

If you want to access the `Str` property, just do the same thing on the `bar` object that's retrieved:

```
PropertyInfo strProperty = 
    bar.GetType().GetProperty("Str", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

MethodInfo strGetter = strProperty.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);

string val = (string)strGetter.Invoke(bar, null);
```

Comment: I misspoke in the body of the question and typed out a question different than the one posed in the title.  I'm not trying to Foo's FooBar, I'm trying to get Foo's FooBar's Str.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I'd tried that but must've had a typo in there somewhere.  It really was as easy as it should have been.

Comment: If you have an instance of `var f = new Foo()`, after `object bar = getter.Invoke(f, null);` bar will still be null and `bar.GetType()...` will fail with NullReferenceException, correct? Did I missed something?

Answer (score 9):

There is a way to slightly simplify [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30763319/3220898).

Replace the calls to `GetGetMethod()` + `Invoke()` with a single call to `GetValue()` :

```cs
PropertyInfo barGetter =
    typeof(Foo).GetProperty("FooBar", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
object bar = barGetter.GetValue(f);

PropertyInfo strGetter =
    bar.GetType().GetProperty("Str", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
string val = (string)strGetter.GetValue(bar);
```

I did some testing, and I didn't find a difference, then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2570933/3220898), which says that `GetValue()` calls `GetGetMethod()` with error checking, so there is no practical difference (unless you worry about performance, but when using Reflection I guess that you won't).